# Entity Framework 6, Postgres (npgsql) and EF Power Tools

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql, ef-power-tools

I have some trouble using the EF Power Tools and I searched now for several days but I didn't find any solution for my problem.

Maybe someone has a new idea or hint for me. My problem is that when I want to create a Preview Data Model VS says that it couldn't find the required ADO.NET driver. I'm working with Postgres and EF 6.

It worked several days before but, as far as I can see within my source control nothing important changed. So I started to search for a solution and tried several things. I guess it has something to do with my app.config but I have no idea what I'm exactly missing there.

The app it self runs great and also the connection to the db works fine, only the EF power tools seems to have a problem.

It would be great if anyone could help me.

Regards Alex